# What is the difference between “methodology” vs. “originality of approach” when reviewing a paper

Tags: peer-review, terminology

I was asked to review a paper with many attributes I should consider. More specifically, I was asked to review the “methodology” and “originality of approach and presentation”.

What is the difference between them in scientific research or as qualities of a paper?

Comment: If you want to know what your advisor means, ask them, not us!

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I think it’s safe to assume that we are talking about a typical peer review or these terms are to be understood as in peer review.

Comment: I don't really see why this is too broad - it's a pretty straightforward question about academic terminology. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt that you were asked to review the “originality of presentation” as this is not a key factor. Sometimes a paper requires an original mode of presentation and that’s fine, but if it doesn’t, that’s better. Thus I assume you were tasked to judge the following three:

- ***Originality of approach*** refers to the central idea and novelty of the paper. Many journals require papers to contain original ideas. So the question you would have to answer is: Does the paper contain novel ideas or insights? And how novel or creative are they?
- ***Methodology*** refers to the application of methods to realise the approach. Were established methods chosen and used appropriately? If new methods were developed, was it necessary and are they any good?
- ***Presentation*** refers to how the research is presented. Is everything intelligible with reasonable effort? Do you have all information necessary to reproduce the research?